# Safest way to find the row of maximum value in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

My data is as follows -

```
x= np.array( ((0,0,0,0), (0,0,0,2.8) ))
```

I want to find the row containing the maximum value. In this example it is 1(0 indexed,hence 1)

`np.argmax(x)` returns the position as 7

I can go the roundabout way by using argmax and ndim to find the maximum value's row number.

I was wondering if there is any other way

I am using Python 2.7. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [7]: import numpy as np

In [8]: x= np.array( ((0,0,0,0), (0,0,0,2.8) ))

In [9]: np.argmax(x.max(axis=1))
Out[9]: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you use `np.argmax(x)` to get `7` you can then do this:

```
>>> np.unravel_index(np.argmax(x), x.shape)
(1, 3)
```

This converts the flat index back a 2D one, and you can easily see which row it is.

Comment: Gives column index too. Thanks.